# How to get all checkboxs and store them by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some checkboxs, now I would like to get all of checkboxs and ids.

for example :

```
<input name="sizes" id="1" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="2" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="3" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="4" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="5" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
```

what I want :

```
//array :::  id:status -> status : 0:unchecked 1:checked

1=>0
2=>1
3=>1
4=>0
5=>1
```

I want to post this array by Ajax .

Comment: Why are you not giving them values and then just using `serialize`?

Comment: plz give me an example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var jsonObj = $("[type='checkbox']").map(function(i, o) {
  return { id : o.id, checked : o.checked  };
});
console.log(jsonObj);

//while posting thru ajax
JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="sizes" id="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="sizes" id="2" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="3" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="4" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
<input name="sizes" id="5" type="checkbox" checked="{{$check}}">
```